# Chrome Extension keypress for Skype Web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, skype

I want to write a Chrome Extension that can send messages using Skype for web (https://web.skype.com/en/). I can get the text in the textarea but I can't get it to trigger the Enter key. How to archive this?

The extension gets loaded ok, and puts a text in the input field, but there it stops. I also tried firing change events and input events. But nothing happens.

I'm using a wait function because Skype takes a while to load.

My manifest.json

```
{ "manifest_version": 2, "name": "SkypeTest", "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["https://web.skype.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "skypeTest.js"]}]}
```

My skypeTest.js

```
    ;(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event( 'keydown', { which: 13 } );
    function init(){
        console.log('Script running');
        var wait = function() {
            var txtArea = $("textarea[name='messageInput']");
            if (txtArea.is(':visible')) {
                clearTimeout(waiting);
                txtArea.val('Hello Skype');
                txtArea.trigger('focus').trigger(e);
            }
        };
        var waiting = setInterval(wait, 5000);
    }
    init();
})();
```

This is the input field

```
<textarea tabindex="10010" maxlength="2000" data-bind="value: messageBody, css: {hide: !isEnabled()},
     valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','propertychange','input'],
     event: { keypress: handleKeyPress, keydown: handleKeyDown, input: handleInput,
     focus: onFocus, blur: onBlur, paste: onPaste }, hasFocus: chatInputFocus,
     l10n_attr: {'placeholder': 'area_text_insertText'}, attr: { 'aria-label': label },
     template: { afterRender: handleFocus }" name="messageInput" class="inputField fontSize-p" placeholder="Type a message here"
     aria-label="Chat input" style="height: 30px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: See [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52408) and [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. I am aware of the bug in Chrome. But this seems to be something else. In the debugger I can see the correct keyCode is assigned: 
n.Event {type: "keydown", which: 13, timeStamp: 1436756197584,      jQuery2140713275273796171: true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible because of Chrome's security features.
I switched to [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) instead.